# error: am__fastdepCXX does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL

Tags: linux, autotools, autoconf

Trying to follow [this](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-magic-behind-configure-make-make-install) tutorial I have done my own "Hello World" in c++.

This is the code `prueba.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hola Mundo"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, I have created `configure.ac` file with this information:

```
AC_INIT([holamundo], [0.1], [address@address.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and `Makefile.am`

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
bin_PROGRAMS = holamundo
holamundo_SOURCES = ./prueba.cpp
```

Those files are in the same folder of `prueba.cpp`

Finnally, in console and in the same folder of `prueba.cpp` I run the commands:

`aclocal` (no errors)

`autoconf` (no errors)

`automake --add-missing` Then I have the next errors:

```
Makefile.am:3: warning: source file './prueba.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
Makefile.am:3: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
automake: At least one source file is in a subdirectory, but the 'subdir-objects'
automake: automake option hasn't been enabled.  For now, the corresponding output
automake: object file(s) will be placed in the top-level directory.  However, this
automake: behavior may change in a future Automake major version, with object
automake: files being placed in the same subdirectory as the corresponding sources.
automake: You are advised to start using 'subdir-objects' option throughout your
automake: project, to avoid future incompatibilities.
/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCXX does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCXX' is to add 'AC_PROG_CXX'
/usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
Makefile.am: error: C++ source seen but 'CXX' is undefined
Makefile.am:   The usual way to define 'CXX' is to add 'AC_PROG_CXX'
Makefile.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'autoconf' again.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue 1

> ```
> Makefile.am:3: warning: source file './prueba.cpp' is in a subdirectory,
> Makefile.am:3: but option 'subdir-objects' is disabled
> automake: warning: possible forward-incompatibility.
> ```

[...]

Do not prefix source names with `./` (or `../`) in **Makefile.am**.

Automake can handle sources and targets in bona fide subdirectories, with or without recursive `make`, but you do need to set up your project for that, and I would not go there until you have a better handle on Autotools basics.

### Issue 2

> ```
> Makefile.am: error: C++ source seen but 'CXX' is undefined
> Makefile.am:   The usual way to define 'CXX' is to add 'AC_PROG_CXX'
> Makefile.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'autoconf' again.
> ```

The diagnostic already explains the problem and the solution, but see also below.

### Issue 3

> ```
> /usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am: error: am__fastdepCXX does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
> /usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'am__fastdepCXX' is to add 'AC_PROG_CXX'
> /usr/share/automake-1.16/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
> ```

Again, the diagnostic already describes a solution.  Since it is *the same* solution that another diagnostic suggests, and that seems plausible and appropriate, that seems to be a pretty good bet.  Specifically:

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([holamundo], [0.1], [address@address.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_PROG_CC

# Configure the C++ compiler:
AC_PROG_CXX

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

### Issue 4

> Finnally, in console and in the same folder of prueba.cpp I run the commands:

Generally speaking, you should not manually run the individual autotools (`autoconf`, `automake`, *etc*.).  Instead, use `autoreconf`, which will identify which of the (other) autotools need to be run, and will run them in the correct order.  Among the command-line options it supports are `-i` / `--install` and `-f` / `--force`, which will provide for installing the local autotool components in the source tree.  You should probably run `autoreconf --install --force` once in your source tree.  After that, you should need only plain `autoreconf`, unless you change to a different version of the autotools or modify one of the local autotool components.

Comment: Thanks. It's a very clear explanation. I was wrong and I though that "add 'AC_PROG_CXX'" mean to change CXX for CPP or CC or similar.